# Mongodb aggregate query using group-by

Tags: mongodb, group-by, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, grouping

My MongoDB stores documents having the following structure:

```
{
    "curl_detail" : {
        "Curl1" : {
            "attack_type" : "attack1",          
            "flag" : "Attack",
            "curl_result" : "Pass"
        },
        "Curl2" : {
            "attack_type" : "attack1",
            "flag" : "Attack",
            "curl_result" : "Pass"
        },
        "Curl3" : {
            "attack_type" : "attack2",
            "flag" : "Attack",
            "curl_result" : "Pass"
        },
        "Curl4" : {
            "attack_type" : "attack3",
            "flag" : "Attack",
            "curl_result" : "Fail"
        }
}
{
    "curl_detail" : {
        "Curl1" : {
            "attack_type" : "attack3",
            "flag" : "Attack",
            "curl_result" : "Pass"
        },
        "Curl2" : {
            "attack_type" : "attack2",
            "flag" : "Attack",
            "curl_result" : "Pass"
        },
        "Curl3" : {
            "attack_type" : "attack3",
            "flag" : "Pass",
            "curl_result" : "Pass"
        },
        "Curl4" : {
            "attack_type" : "attack1",
            "flag" : "Attack",
            "curl_result" : "Fail"
        }
}
```

How can I perform MongoDB aggregation to achieve the following output:

```
[{
    attack: "attack1",
    expected: 3,
    actual: 2
},
{
    attack:"attack2",
    expected: 2,
    actual: 2
},
{
    attack: "attack3",
    expected: 2,
    actual: 2
}]
```

Explanation for output required:

1. I need to group by the *attack_type* field corresponding to each curl present in the *curl_detail*.
2. Now the ***expected*** field in the output is the sum of *"flag"* key having value as *"Attack"* (Note that *"Pass"* values are not included in the sum. See the ***expected*** value  ***attack3*** in the output for more clarification)
3. And the ***actual*** field in the output is the sum of *"curl_result"* key having value as *"Pass"*. (Note that *"Fail"* values are not included in the sum)
4. The sum calculated for ***expected*** value of output depends only on *"flag"* key and the sum calculated for ***actual*** value of output depends only on the *"curl_result"* key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "curl_detail": {
      "$objectToArray": "$curl_detail"
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$curl_detail" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$curl_detail.v.attack_type",
    "expected": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$eq": ["$curl_detail.v.flag", "Attack"] },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    },
    "actual": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$eq": ["$curl_detail.v.curl_result", "Pass"] },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$addFields": { "attack": "$_id", "_id": "$$REMOVE" }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dh2vdWeDGjI)

Comment: Your output is misleading. See your point in the list if "Pass" is not included then how  "attack1" is having "expected" = 3? Same for the "attack2" both should have expected as 1 and 0 respectively.

Comment: I had added 4th point in the explanation above to make it more clear. `how "attack1" is having "expected" = 3?` So basically, Curl1 and Curl2 (in document 1) and Curl4 (in document 2) has `"flag" : "Attack",` , that's why the _expected_ was summed up to 3. Same goes for "attack2" as well. Curl3 (in document 1) and Curl2 (in document 2) has `"flag" : "Attack",` , hence the _expected_ value was summed to 2 for "attack2"  . Let me know if you need more clarification on this. Thanks!!!

Comment: If "actual" value depends on "curl_result" key then "attack3" should have "actual" = 2? because it has "curl_result" = "pass" = 2  ??

Comment: Thanks mate!!! It worked like a charm. I don't know if you noticed this or not, but in the final output, I am getting `"_id":"attack1"` instead of `"attack":"attack1"`